# Tcboxedraster forces a 1 column even when I've stated 2?

Tags: two-column, tcolorbox

I am in the middle of writing my thesis, and have to put together a SWOT analysis. I want it to be a 2x2 table, that looks like this:

[image: Supposed to look like this]

Instead, the table is 1 column which I can't seem to fix. I have specifically stated: raster columns=2, which is what I've done in the picture above. Can someone help?

This is what it looks like now: [image: This is what it looks like now]

I have pasted my code below:

```
\begin{tcboxedraster}[raster columns=2, raster equal height=rows,
size=small,colframe=swotW!80!black,colback=white,colbacktitle=swotS!80!black,
title={Box \# \thetcbrasternum}]
{colframe=swotW!80!black,colback=white,fonttitle=\bfseries,title=SWOT model 
for Bavarian Nordic}

\begin{tcolorbox}[equal height group=1, size=fbox, colframe=swotS!80!black, 
title=\large{\textsc{styrker}}]
\begin{enumerate} 
\item \small{Stærkt relationelt bånd til amerikansk \\ regering og andre 
instanser}
\item \small{Diversificeret præparatportefølje}
\item \small{Teknologisk platform som fundament \\ for overbevisende 
kliniske resultater} 
\item \small{Synergietablering mellem portefølje \\ og demografisk 
udvikling}
\end{enumerate}
\end{tcolorbox}


\begin{tcolorbox}[equal height group=1, size=fbox, colframe=swotW!80!black, title=\large{\textsc{svagheder}}] 
\begin{enumerate}
\item \small{PROSTVACs kommercielle succes i \\ BMS' hænder}
\item \small{Manglende likviditet fører til afhængig- \\ hed af sponsorer}
\item \small{Svagt fundament for kommercialisering af\\  RSV}
\end{enumerate}

\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[equal height group=2, size=fbox, colframe=swotO!80!black, 
title=\large{\textsc{muligheder}}] 
\begin{enumerate}
\item \small{Geopolitisk klimaeskalering}
\item \small{Ældrende befolkning}
\item \small{Monopol-lignende status for tredje- \\generations koppevaccine i USA}
\item \small{Europæisk transition til tredje- \\ generations koppevaccine}
\end{enumerate}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=\large{\textsc{trusler}}]
\begin{enumerate}
\item \small{Biosimilars i takt med patentudløb}
\item \small{Fluktuerende US-dollar}
\item \small{Intensivering af utilfredshed med pris- \\niveau i USA}
\item \small{Ophøring af Obamacare grundet \\ sundhedspolitisk reform under Trump \\ der kan skabe flere forsikringsløse}
\end{enumerate}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{tcboxedraster}
```

Comment: Don't leave empty lines between `tcolorboxes`, they start a new paragraph. If you want a blank line between them, place `%` as the first character.

Comment: @Ignasi: Please write an answer in order to kick this from the unanswered list ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even inside a `tcbraster` or `tcboxedrater`, empty lines between `tcolorboxes` start a new paragraph. This is the reason for one column result in posted code.

If you don't want to suppress all space between tcolorboxes, use a `%` to comment the empty lines:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}
...
\end{tcolorbox}
%
\begin{tcolorbox}
...
\end{tcolorbox}
```

Your after completion and correction:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\colorlet{swotS}{red}
\colorlet{swotW}{blue}
\colorlet{swotO}{green}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcboxedraster}[raster columns=2, raster equal height=rows,
size=small,colframe=swotW!80!black,colback=white,colbacktitle=swotS!80!black,
title={Box \# \thetcbrasternum}]
{colframe=swotW!80!black,colback=white,fonttitle=\bfseries,title=SWOT model 
for Bavarian Nordic}

\begin{tcolorbox}[equal height group=1, size=fbox, colframe=swotS!80!black, 
title=\large{\textsc{styrker}}]
\begin{enumerate} 
\item \small{Stærkt relationelt bånd til amerikansk \\ regering og andre 
instanser}
\item \small{Diversificeret præparatportefølje}
\item \small{Teknologisk platform som fundament \\ for overbevisende 
kliniske resultater} 
\item \small{Synergietablering mellem portefølje \\ og demografisk 
udvikling}
\end{enumerate}
\end{tcolorbox}
%
\begin{tcolorbox}[equal height group=1, size=fbox, colframe=swotW!80!black, title=\large{\textsc{svagheder}}] 
\begin{enumerate}
\item \small{PROSTVACs kommercielle succes i \\ BMS' hænder}
\item \small{Manglende likviditet fører til afhængig- \\ hed af sponsorer}
\item \small{Svagt fundament for kommercialisering af\\  RSV}
\end{enumerate}
\end{tcolorbox}
%
\begin{tcolorbox}[equal height group=2, size=fbox, colframe=swotO!80!black, 
title=\large{\textsc{muligheder}}] 
\begin{enumerate}
\item \small{Geopolitisk klimaeskalering}
\item \small{Ældrende befolkning}
\item \small{Monopol-lignende status for tredje- \\generations koppevaccine i USA}
\item \small{Europæisk transition til tredje- \\ generations koppevaccine}
\end{enumerate}
\end{tcolorbox}
%
\begin{tcolorbox}[equal height group=2, title=\large{\textsc{trusler}}]
\begin{enumerate}
\item \small{Biosimilars i takt med patentudløb}
\item \small{Fluktuerende US-dollar}
\item \small{Intensivering af utilfredshed med pris- \\niveau i USA}
\item \small{Ophøring af Obamacare grundet \\ sundhedspolitisk reform under Trump \\ der kan skabe flere forsikringsløse}
\end{enumerate}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{tcboxedraster}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]